# UITextField always results in nil

Tags: swift, uitextfield, textfield

I'm trying to get the information of a UITextField and then reuse that data from the UITextField with swift 2.0 and Xcode 7. But every time I run the app, the app crashes and says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

even though there is something in the textfield.
Someone knows how to solve this problem?

This is how my code looks:

```
@IBOutlet weak var entryAmount: UITextField! //TextField declaration
@IBAction func saveNewButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //update overall amount
        let amount: String? = self.entryAmount.text! //Throws the error at this point
        self.viewController.currentValue += amount
}
```

In another function, I wrote the same thing ("let amount: String? = entryAmount.text!") and when I printed "amount", it showed the right result. But as soon as I tried to use it further, "amount" was always set to nil, even tough it always printed the right result in the beginning.

I encounter the same thing with DatePicker, Switches and updating Button texts.

Someone knows something to help me? - Thanks

Btw I'm pretty new to swift and Xcode.

**Update:** Could it be because the TextField is in a ContainerView?

**Update Two:** I'm pretty much sure the problem is because of the ContainerView. I tried a TextField that isn't in a containerView and didn't get the error, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Try to debug with `po` command. When it throws, type `po self.entryAmount` to check if it nil. Or `po self.entryAmout.text` to check if `text` is nil.

Comment: I tried that and both are nil. `(lldb) po self.entryAmount
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
nil

(lldb) po self.entryAmount.text
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your Interface Builder that the UITextField is properly linked to your "entryAmount" IBOutlet. It might be the case that they are not properly connected and that's why the value is nil at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sample Code]

I could be wrong but what it seems like from your question is you're having trouble with scoping. Any variables you declare in a function are scoped only to that function.

Declaring amount in saveNewButtonTapped means amount is only set in that function. Using amount in another function will result in amount being nil. If you want to use variables between functions you need to declare them outside of a function.

In the example I have the var runningAmount. In the example, if I press the button that calls pressAnotherButton, I get the same fatal error you get because I'm unwrapping self.runningAmount before it's been set. But if I press the button that calls saveNewButtonTapped, even with nothing in the textfield, then press the button that calls pressAnotherButton, I get the output in the photo.

Comment: The textfield is declared at the beginning of the class and at the end of the class the function is declared, if this is what you mean.

Comment: Meant more like is the code in the subclass of a ViewController? What do you mean by container? It's a subview of a uiview?

Comment: Yes it is in a subclass  of UIViewController. I just tried what you said, but I still get the error and it is still nil. With container I mean that the TextField is in a containerView and I think that this is the problem. Because I tried another TextField that isn't in a containerView and it worked perfectly fine. - Thanks for the help!